# Prolog query to find largest element in database?

Tags: prolog

If I have defined all the digits in a Prolog database, such as `dig(0), dig(1), ..., dig(9)`. What query can I use for Prolog to return the largest digit -- in this case, 9?

I tried something like:

```
?- dig(N), dig(M), N > M.
```

But that just returns the first possibility, not the largest number.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701693

Comment: possible duplicate of [Max out of values defined by prolog clauses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701693/max-out-of-values-defined-by-prolog-clauses)

Answer (score 1):

To find out the largest number you should write an appropriate query, namely one that:

- Instantiate a digit
- Checks whether that digit is the largest (i.e. no other digit is larger)

So you might want to write something like:

```
largest(N):-
    dig(N),
    not((
        dig(M),
        M > N
    )).
```

Comment: This works but has a poor complexity, namely O(n^2). It is possible to do this query in O(n).

Answer (score 1):

While the shortest solution is probably:

```
?- dig(Max), \+((dig(X), X > Max)).
```

the conceptually simplest solution might be:

```
?- findall(X, dig(X), Digits), max_list(Digits, Max).
```

But check out [Max out of values defined by prolog clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701693) for more solutions, with better and worse complexities.

You can test the speed of these two solutions by consulting this file:

```
:- between(1, 12345, X), assert(dig(X)), fail ; true.

:- time((findall(X, dig(X), Digits), max_list(Digits, Max))),
       write('Findall max: '), write(Max), nl.

:- time((dig(Max), \+((dig(X), X > Max)))), write('\\+ max: '), write(Max), nl.
```

On my 5 years old laptop it clearly shows that the `findall`-version is much faster if you have e.g. *12345* entries in your database.

```
% 37,085 inferences, 0.05 CPU in 0.06 seconds (87% CPU, 741700 Lips)
Findall max: 12345
% 76,230,375 inferences, 60.94 CPU in 72.30 seconds (84% CPU, 1250909 Lips)
\+ max: 12345
```