# prolog question find maximum using negation operator \+

Tags: prolog, max, negation

I have got some values H, and I would like to find the maximum one using \+, how can i do it?

```
maxValue(X) :-
  Get(Id, X),
  \+( Get(Id, Y), X < Y ).
```

don't have a clue....please help, thanks!

Comment: Please place a backslash before the backslash so that it becomes visible as a backslash. Only needed when not marked as code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Max out of values defined by prolog clauses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701693/max-out-of-values-defined-by-prolog-clauses)

Answer (score 3):

Using negation is one way to find the maximum. And it really works. 
Here is an example:

```
   p(2).  
   p(1).  
   p(3).  

   ?- p(X), \+ (p(Y), Y > X).  
   X = 3
```

But the complexity will be O(n*n) where n is
the number of facts. But the maximum can be
determined in O(n). So maybe the following is
more efficient for large fact bases:

```
   :- dynamic(the_max/1).  
   update_max(X) :-  
      the_max(Y), X>Y, !, retract(the_max(Y)), assertz(the_max(X)).  
   update_max(_).  

   find_max(X) :-  
      assertz(the_max(0)),  
      (p(Y), update_max(Y), fail; true),  
      retract(the_max(X)).  

   ?- find_max(X).  
   X = 3
```

But watch out, when you use it from multiple threads,
you need to adapt it a little, i.e. make the_max
thread local.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

See also these questions/answers:

- [Prolog query to find largest element in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052794/prolog-query-to-find-largest-element-in-database)
- [Max out of values defined by prolog clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701693/max-out-of-values-defined-by-prolog-clauses)